# Place text to the bottom instead of right below the other text

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm using different DIV tags to act as tables and I want to get another DIV at the bottom of the content DIV.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">

        <div class="table-information">
            Content
        </div>

        <div class="table-content">
            More content

            <div class="extra">
                Here's the extra content
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table-information {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 150px;
}

.table-content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.extra {
    vertical-align: bottom
}
```

As you can see I have `vertical-align: bottom;` for the `extra` class. I want to have the content within that DIV at the bottom and not right below the text `More content`. But nothing happens when I'm trying this solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/3jjbV/

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom` applies to the content of `.extra`, not the `div` itself.

Comment: Ok. How can I make the DIV and it's content at the bottom of the `table-content` DIV tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is 1 way to achieve that

```
.table-content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
}
.extra {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I do it by adding relative position to the container `table-content` and then absolute positioning bottom to the `extra`.
here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/3jjbV/2/)

---

Another way is like this:

```
.extra {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display:table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/3jjbV/5/) for the 2nd option.
From these 2 options personally i would go with the 1st one, 
but you should be careful with the fixed widths and heights (because of the absolute positioning).

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! :D I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. I will use your first solution and I will be careful for the fixed heights and widths :)